# ffmpeg unable to parse really long command; Invalid duration specification for to: 00:0011

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, syntax-error

I'm trying to run an extremely long ffmpeg command but I end up getting an unusual error. I have the following command in a `.cmd` file:

```
ffmpeg -ss "00:00:00" -to 00:00:10 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-morena-oliver-gustavo-9778487.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:23 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_5112050.mp4" -ss 00:00:03 -to 00:00:29 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-kelly-lacy-9468768.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:19 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_3925550.mp4" -ss 00:00:04 -to 00:00:30 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_3999405.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:20 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-taryn-elliott-8549416.mp4" -ss 00:00:11 -to 00:00:37 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-anni-a-5285672.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:26 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-jill-burrow-7681520.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:27 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-bokor-marketing-10301571.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:20 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4631227.mp4" -ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:36 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_5108686.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4742117.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:18 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-missdeena-9934612.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:27 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4420218.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_5108686.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Pexels Videos 4625.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4742117.mp4" -ss 00:00:03 -to 00:00:29 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4919507.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:15 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Pexels Videos 1484703.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:08 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_3816406.mp4" -ss 00:00:04 -to 00:00:30 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4757483.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:16 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-hemanth-k-m-5487781.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "transformed\rain\Pexels Videos 2059694.mp4" -ss 00:00:15 -to 00:00:41 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Pexels Videos 4618.mp4" -ss 00:00:04 -to 00:00:30 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4472112.mp4" -ss 00:00:23 -to 00:00:49 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Pexels Videos 1774955.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:20 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_5025886.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:27 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-francesco-ungaro-5227362.mp4" -ss 00:00:07 -to 00:00:33 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-atypeek-dgn-7043616.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:24 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4919509.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:20 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-taryn-elliott-8549416.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:11 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_3816627.mp4" -ss 00:00:14 -to 00:00:40 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4184080.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:26 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_5156396.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4779388.mp4" -ss 00:00:03 -to 00:00:29 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-nelson-5843699.mp4" -ss 00:00:27 -to 00:00:53 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-okayama-candle-yutoridx-6445790.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_5156396.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:16 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-anastasia-shuraeva-7663345.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:27 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_5155678.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:14 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4933583.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:11 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4171515.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:25 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_3999435.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-anastasia-shuraeva-7663145.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:19 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4112833.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:14 -i "transformed\rain\Pexels Videos 2491284.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:14 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-marc-onana-6070850.mp4" -ss 00:00:05 -to 00:00:31 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-anni-a-5285672.mp4" -ss 00:01:23 -to 00:01:49 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Pexels Videos 1841455.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:14 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4198961.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:14 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4198961.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:14 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-marc-onana-6070850.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-morena-oliver-gustavo-9778487.mp4" -ss 00:00:18 -to 00:00:44 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4306829.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:20 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_5025886.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:23 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-shashank-kumar-5526255.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:19 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4112833.mp4" -ss 00:00:06 -to 00:00:32 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4472112.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:27 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4779388.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:11 -i "transformed\rain\video.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:19 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-muriel-7843122.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:16 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-anastasia-shuraeva-7663345.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:17 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4059704.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:24 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4919509.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:23 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-shashank-kumar-5526255.mp4" -ss 00:00:06 -to 00:00:32 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-francesco-ungaro-5227362.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:15 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-ivan-khmelyuk-9345855.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:15 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-khanhhoangminh-10761873.mp4" -ss 00:00:06 -to 00:00:32 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4757483.mp4" -ss 00:00:08 -to 00:00:34 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\video (1).mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-taryn-elliott-8549483.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:11 -i "transformed\rain\video.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:15 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4272853.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:15 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4272853.mp4" -ss 00:00:18 -to 00:00:44 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4306829.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:19 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_3925550.mp4" -ss 00:00:04 -to 00:00:30 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-kelly-lacy-9632864.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_5155678.mp4" -ss 00:00:05 -to 00:00:31 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-atypeek-dgn-7043616.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:14 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4933583.mp4" -ss 00:01:18 -to 00:01:44 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Pexels Videos 1841455.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:15 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Pexels Videos 1484703.mp4" -ss 00:00:24 -to 00:00:50 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\base_video.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:27 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4420218.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:27 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4184080.mp4" -ss 00:00:45 -to 00:01:11 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-nelson-5784640.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4919507.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:11 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4171515.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:19 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-muriel-7843122.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:25 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_3999435.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-kelly-lacy-9632864.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:26 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Pexels Videos 4618.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:26 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-jill-burrow-7681520.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:23 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_5112050.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:26 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-ratikanta-mallick-5327689.mp4" -ss 00:00:24 -to 00:00:50 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Pexels Videos 1774955.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:27 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-ratikanta-mallick-5327689.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_3999405.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:23 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-jill-burrow-7681526.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-anastasia-shuraeva-7663145.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:27 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-punit-kumar-6040646.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:23 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-jill-burrow-7681526.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Pexels Videos 4625.mp4" -ss 00:00:03 -to 00:00:29 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\base_video.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:20 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4631227.mp4" -ss 00:00:06 -to 00:00:32 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-punit-kumar-6040646.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:14 -i "transformed\rain\Pexels Videos 2491284.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:11 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_3816627.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:18 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-missdeena-9934612.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:08 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_3816406.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:17 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4059704.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:15 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-khanhhoangminh-10761873.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-kelly-lacy-9468768.mp4" -ss 00:00:04 -to 00:00:30 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-bokor-marketing-10301571.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-nelson-5843699.mp4" -ss 00:00:13 -to 00:00:39 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\video (1).mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-taryn-elliott-8549483.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:15 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-ivan-khmelyuk-9345855.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "transformed\rain\Pexels Videos 2059694.mp4" -ss 00:00:09 -to 00:00:35 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-nelson-5784640.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:16 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-hemanth-k-m-5487781.mp4" -ss 00:00:17 -to 00:00:43 -i "transformed\rain\pexels-okayama-candle-yutoridx-6445790.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=7:duration=3[1v];[1v][2:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=27:duration=3[2v];[2v][3:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=50:duration=3[3v];[3v][4:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=66:duration=3[4v];[4v][5:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=89:duration=3[5v];[5v][6:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=106:duration=3[6v];[6v][7:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=129:duration=3[7v];[7v][8:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=152:duration=3[8v];[8v][9:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=175:duration=3[9v];[9v][10:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=192:duration=3[10v];[10v][11:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=215:duration=3[11v];[11v][12:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=222:duration=3[12v];[12v][13:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=237:duration=3[13v];[13v][14:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=260:duration=3[14v];[14v][15:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=283:duration=3[15v];[15v][16:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=290:duration=3[16v];[16v][17:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=297:duration=3[17v];[17v][18:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=320:duration=3[18v];[18v][19:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=332:duration=3[19v];[19v][20:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=337:duration=3[20v];[20v][21:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=360:duration=3[21v];[21v][22:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=373:duration=3[22v];[22v][23:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=380:duration=3[23v];[23v][24:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=403:duration=3[24v];[24v][25:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=426:duration=3[25v];[25v][26:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=449:duration=3[26v];[26v][27:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=466:duration=3[27v];[27v][28:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=489:duration=3[28v];[28v][29:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=512:duration=3[29v];[29v][30:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=533:duration=3[30v];[30v][31:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=550:duration=3[31v];[31v][32:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=558:duration=3[32v];[32v][33:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=581:duration=3[33v];[33v][34:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=604:duration=3[34v];[34v][35:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=627:duration=3[35v];[35v][36:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=650:duration=3[36v];[36v][37:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=673:duration=3[37v];[37v][38:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=696:duration=3[38v];[38v][39:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=709:duration=3[39v];[39v][40:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=732:duration=3[40v];[40v][41:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=743:duration=3[41v];[41v][42:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=751:duration=3[42v];[42v][43:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=773:duration=3[43v];[43v][44:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=780:duration=3[44v];[44v][45:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=796:duration=3[45v];[45v][46:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=807:duration=3[46v];[46v][47:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=818:duration=3[47v];[47v][48:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=841:duration=3[48v];[48v][49:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=864:duration=3[49v];[49v][50:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=875:duration=3[50v];[50v][51:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=886:duration=3[51v];[51v][52:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=897:duration=3[52v];[52v][53:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=904:duration=3[53v];[53v][54:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=927:duration=3[54v];[54v][55:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=944:duration=3[55v];[55v][56:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=964:duration=3[56v];[56v][57:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=980:duration=3[57v];[57v][58:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1003:duration=3[58v];[58v][59:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1026:duration=3[59v];[59v][60:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1034:duration=3[60v];[60v][61:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1050:duration=3[61v];[61v][62:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1063:duration=3[62v];[62v][63:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1077:duration=3[63v];[63v][64:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1098:duration=3[64v];[64v][65:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1118:duration=3[65v];[65v][66:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1141:duration=3[66v];[66v][67:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1153:duration=3[67v];[67v][68:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1165:duration=3[68v];[68v][69:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1188:duration=3[69v];[69v][70:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1211:duration=3[70v];[70v][71:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1218:duration=3[71v];[71v][72:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1226:duration=3[72v];[72v][73:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1238:duration=3[73v];[73v][74:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1250:duration=3[74v];[74v][75:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1273:duration=3[75v];[75v][76:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1289:duration=3[76v];[76v][77:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1312:duration=3[77v];[77v][78:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1335:duration=3[78v];[78v][79:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1358:duration=3[79v];[79v][80:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1369:duration=3[80v];[80v][81:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1392:duration=3[81v];[81v][82:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1404:duration=3[82v];[82v][83:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1427:duration=3[83v];[83v][84:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1450:duration=3[84v];[84v][85:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1473:duration=3[85v];[85v][86:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1496:duration=3[86v];[86v][87:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1519:duration=3[87v];[87v][88:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1527:duration=3[88v];[88v][89:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1543:duration=3[89v];[89v][90:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1565:duration=3[90v];[90v][91:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1588:duration=3[91v];[91v][92:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1611:duration=3[92v];[92v][93:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1634:duration=3[93v];[93v][94:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1654:duration=3[94v];[94v][95:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1677:duration=3[95v];[95v][96:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1700:duration=3[96v];[96v][97:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1723:duration=3[97v];[97v][98:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1746:duration=3[98v];[98v][99:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1766:duration=3[99v];[99v][100:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1773:duration=3[100v];[100v][101:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1796:duration=3[101v];[101v][102:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1816:duration=3[102v];[102v][103:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1823:duration=3[103v];[103v][104:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1846:duration=3[104v];[104v][105:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1863:duration=3[105v];[105v][106:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1886:duration=3[106v];[106v][107:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1897:duration=3[107v];[107v][108:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1905:duration=3[108v];[108v][109:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1920:duration=3[109v];[109v][110:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1925:duration=3[110v];[110v][111:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1939:duration=3[111v];[111v][112:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1951:duration=3[112v];[112v][113:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1974:duration=3[113v];[113v][114:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1997:duration=3[114v];[114v][115:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=2020:duration=3[115v];[115v][116:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=2043:duration=3[116v];[116v][117:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=2050:duration=3[117v];[117v][118:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=2062:duration=3[118v];[118v][119:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=2069:duration=3[119v];[119v][120:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=2092:duration=3[120v];[120v][121:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=2105:duration=3[121v]" -map [121v] -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 18 -c:a aac -q:a 4 -map_metadata -1 output.mp4 -y -hide_banner
```

When I run this I get the following output:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-morena-oliver-gustavo-9778487.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.77, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7875 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 7872 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_5112050.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.100
  Duration: 00:00:23.63, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2576 kb/s
  Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 2573 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'transformed\rain\pexels-kelly-lacy-9468768.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.100
  Duration: 00:00:30.87, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18831 kb/s
  Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 18828 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'transformed\rain\production ID_3925550.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.100
  Duration: 00:00:19.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6552 kb/s
  Stream #3:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 6549 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_3999405.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.100
  Duration: 00:00:35.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3374 kb/s
  Stream #4:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3371 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #5, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-taryn-elliott-8549416.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.100
  Duration: 00:00:20.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3399 kb/s
  Stream #5:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3396 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #6, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'transformed\rain\pexels-anni-a-5285672.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.100
  Duration: 00:00:42.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5201 kb/s
  Stream #6:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 5198 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #7, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'transformed\rain\pexels-jill-burrow-7681520.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.100
  Duration: 00:00:27.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3461 kb/s
  Stream #7:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3458 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  
...

Input #15, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Pexels Videos 4625.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6029 kb/s
  Stream #15:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 6026 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #16, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4742117.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10139 kb/s
  Stream #16:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 10135 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #17, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4919507.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.100
  Duration: 00:00:34.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5249 kb/s
  Stream #17:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 5246 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

... (abbreviating because this post must be less than 30,000)

Input #85, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\pexels-nelson-5784640.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.100
  Duration: 00:01:14.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14026 kb/s
  Stream #85:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 14023 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #86, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4919507.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.100
  Duration: 00:00:34.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5249 kb/s
  Stream #86:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 5246 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Invalid duration specification for to: 00:0011
```

I don't really understand what's going wrong here; if you look at the input ffmpeg command, you'll see that there is no `-to` flag immediately followed by `00:0011` as the error message claims (scroll to the bottom). When I run that particular trim on the file in question separately, it is able to trim it just fine. You can also see that the input file is used prior to `input #86` and doesn't receive this issue (see `input #17`).

My only thought is that it has something to do with the command itself being so long. Is it possible that ffmpeg is not able to parse the command correctly because it is so long? I'm on Windows 10 with ffmpeg version `ffmpeg version 2021-07-14-git-ca56299fb3-full_build-www.gyan.dev`. I get the same issue in both powershell and cmd. I am running it from a .cmd file because Windows won't let me run it from command line directly because it is longer than 8192 characters.

Comment: May be this? [Command prompt (Cmd. exe) command-line string limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/command-line-string-limitation)

Comment: @kesh, that might be the issue, but the problem is the recommended solution is to "modify the program to use a command line that is similar to the following command line, where ParameterFile is a file that contains the required parameters (parameter1 parameter2... ParameterN)." Can ffmpeg do something like this? I'm not sure how that syntax works given the -ss and -to flags.

Comment: yeah, I wasn't sure how you can address it with your current approach. 2 ways to shorten your command: (1) run ffmpeg in your base folder `F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed` so you omit that part of the path from all your files (2) use seconds notation for the `-ss` and  `-to`

Comment: @kesh, unfortunately that won't work when I have thousands of inputs, which is what I plan on scaling this up to. I think I'll just have to recursively subdivide the problem until each individual ffmpeg command is small enough. I may run into compression issues that way, but I guess if each intermediate file isn't too heavily compressed it could be OK.